# Oracle ORDS: Get request returns old data, then after period of time the changed data

Tags: oracle, rest, tomcat, configuration, oracle-rest-data-services

I am having a problem with the Oracle Rest Data Services (short ORDS) and I can't find a solution.

The Problem is as follows:

We are using ORDS via a TomCat Webserver and I have 2 Endpoints defined, one to Update a dataset and one to get all datasets from this table.
If I update the value via my Endpoint the change is written in the Table, but if I try to get the table with this change ORDS only response with the old not changed table. After a certain period of Time while constantly trying to get the change it repondes with the expected values. (happens after max 1 minute, can be earlier).

Because of this behaviour I accused some type of caching, but I cant find no configuration in the oracle database or on the TomCat.

Another Point for this theory was that I logged what happens in my GET procedure and found that only the one request with the correct values gets logged, like the others didnt even happen ..

The Request giving me the old value are coming back in the 4-8 ms range while the request with the correct data is in the 100-200 ms.

Ty for your help :)

I tried logging what happens, but I got that only the request with the fresh values was logged.

I tried to restart the TomCat Webserver to make sure that the cache is cleared, but this didnt fix the Problem

I searched for a configuration in ORDS or oracle where a cache would be defined, but it was never set.

I tried to set the value via a SQL update and not an endpoint, but even here I get the change only delayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a full overview of the communication path? Maybe there is a proxy between?
When the TomCat has no caching configuration and you restartet the webserver during your tests and still have the same issue, then there is maybe more...
Kind regards
M-Achilles

Comment: Hey, thank you for your help. I found  that the IIS that handels my request and gives them to the TomCat. On the IIS-Server was caching enabled and after disabling it ORDS reacted as I wished!